# When will dequeueReusableCell return nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to the iOS programming scene and I recently came across some code examples online of implementations like:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CustomCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier) asCustomCell
        }
    ...
    }
```

Where the author tried to handle the event where `dequeueReusableCell` return nil.

But from my limited personal experience with UITableView and custom cells, I have yet to encounter a time when `dequeueReusableCell` returned me nil.

From researching, I found the reason could be

> "The dequeue… methods try to find a cell with the given reuse
> identifier that is currently offscreen. If they find one, they return
> that cell, otherwise they return nil."

[from MrTJ's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997857/why-does-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-return-nil-after-cell-alloc/36998454)

But that has never happened once to me. When I purposely give it a wrong identifier, a runtime error would occur but not once was nil returned. I wonder when exactly that would happen and if handling it is really necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code isn't correct. The older form of `dequeueReusableCell` without the `indexPath` parameter returns `nil` when there isn't an available cell in the reuse pool (i.e. when the table view first appears). In that case it is your responsibility to allocate a cell.

The newer form of `dequeueResuableCell`, shown in your question, will always return a cell as it allocates a cell if required.

The expression in your question can return `nil` if the conditional downcast fails (that is, the cell that was returned wasn't an instance of `CustomCell`).

I would argue that this represents a serious misconfiguration somewhere and should be found during development.  For this reason a forced downcast is normally used; during development you get a crash, fix the problem and move on.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

The code in your question is some sort of Frankenstein mixture of the old and the new.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That explained it precisely. Looks like I joined the scene at an interesting time when what this function does completely covered up the fact that a pool exists for me. From my standpoint, I think the mane of this function does not precisely describe what it does anymore and should be renamed/become a new function instead.